# Count Number of group items that appear on a page

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I would like to be able to count the group header items that appear on a page of a report in SSRS.

if the report would look like this (below), I would like to calculate the number of items shown on the Page Footer.

---

### PageHeader Page 1

Group 1

```
  detail 1
```

Group 2

```
  detail 1
  detail 2
```

Group 3

```
  detail 1
  detail 2
  detail 3
```

Group 4

```
  detail 1
  detail 2
  detail 3
```

---

Page Footer (showing 4 items on this page)

---

### PageHeader Page 2

Group 5

```
  detail 1
  detail 2
  detail 3
```

Group 6

```
  detail 1
  detail 2
```

Group 7

```
  detail 1
  detail 2
  detail 3
```

---

Page Footer (showing 3 items on this page)

---

I have tried using

```
[CountDistinct(xxx)]
Row_Number() 
CountRows()
```

Comment: what should happen when the group splits across multiple pages?

Comment: What is your `CountDistinct` counting?  Have you tried specifying the scope as the group?

Comment: If the group splits across pages, just the number of items on each page are needed

Comment: CountDistinct does not give me the items on EACH page. I think code is needed to count group items on each page.

Comment: @Harry, Please see answer to your question above